How can I apply a date restriction for a part of my query on the meta_query?
I have created a code like the one below. What I want to achieve with my code is to list all the products that are in stock on my e-commerce site. However, I want to list products that are out of stock but were added up to a maximum of 6 months ago. However, I couldn't manage to do it. Can't I use the date_query part for a specific portion of the query? Or can you suggest a different scenario? Thank you.
    function custom_woocommerce_product_query($query) {
        if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
            $date_six_months_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 months'));
    
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_stock_status',
                    'value' => 'instock',
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => 'outofstock',
                    ),
                ),
            );
    
            $date_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_date',
                    'after' => $date_six_months_ago,
                    'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            );
    
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
            $query->set('date_query', $date_query);
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_woocommerce_product_query');


